# How to Add Text to Hierarchal Column Header of Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Kendo Grid and MVC to display detail data.

I have a Kendo grid that has a Hierarchal/Detail grid that is expandable.  I need to Add title text to the column header of the main grid, where the image is located in the main grid.

From what I've read, I think I need to add the logic in the Main Grid's Databound event, beyond that, I'm a bit lost.

[Column needing Title Text](http://screencast.com/t/Y8IEQzfvgYk5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by hooking up a databound event to the main grid:

```html
.Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBoundMain"))
```

Then I added this JQuery, which also included a fix to remove an extra &nbsp that was being inserted:

```js
function onDataBoundMain() {
        $(".k-hierarchy-cell.k-header").append("<span class='k-link'>Details</span>");
        
        $('.k-hierarchy-cell.k-header').html(function(i,h){
            return h.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
        });
    }
```